# Trouble loading .PNG in article class

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I'm in the process of writing my thesis, and am having trouble getting any images to load in my document. I'm using the article class, as it required the least amount of editing to get it to look like what I am after. When I try to add a picture using `\includegraphics{picture}`, it compiles file but when I try to open the PDF it tells me "File Not Found". I tried changing the class to report and it compiled fine. The error I get is :

> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `G:/Documents/Windows 7/Documents/Spring 2014/
>   Thesis/Thesis/WOpic.png' not found.

but this is the correct location and the file exists. Here's the beginning of the document and what packages i'm using. Also, I'm using TexMaker for editing and compiling.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{cite,titletoc,tocloft,afterpage,setspace,graphicx,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
```

Any ideas as to what the issue could be?

Comment: There is many things, that you could try. Try another `.png`. Try moving it to another location: one dir up, two dir up, ... . Try simpler test document. Try systematically, and you will be able to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: ...anyway - does window not use backslash for paths!?

Comment: Welcome to the site! The space in your directory could cause some issues

Comment: Use `\usepackage{grffile}` to take care of spaces, or enclose the entire pathe in quotes `"..."`

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't try this before, but it seems to be a problem with the specific picture I'm using. Any idea what could be wrong with the image? I have it saved as a .png, and can load a different .png just fine in the same document.

Comment: Has this problem been resolved? If not, please make the problematic image available for download and add a link to your question.